# What is the significance of mentioning-sides of a triangle?

Tags: notation

During solving inequalities I have often come across questions where it is mentioned that the variables involved are sides of a triangle.

One eg.-$a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.Show that,$\frac 12< \frac {ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\leq1.$.

So,what is the significance of mentioning **sides of a triangle**?Why is this geometric assumption drawn in a problem which does not involve geometry?What other ways a re there to write this statement?

Answer (score 1):

If $a, b, c$ are sides of a triangle, we can express: $$a=x+y\\b=y+z\\c=z+x$$ for positive $x, y, z$. Another way to put it is: $$a<b+c\\b<c+a\\c<a+b$$

The right hand side is a simple inequality that can be solved with various techniques like AM-GM or Rearrangement.

Here your example inequality becomes:

$$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\frac{(x+y)(y+z)+(y+z)(z+x)+(z+x)(x+y)}{(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2}\\=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+3xy+3yz+3zx}{2x^2+2y^2+2z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx}\\=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2xy+2yz+2zx}{2x^2+2y^2+2z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx}>\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: can you have a triangle with sides of length 1, 2, and 37? Try to draw it - what goes wrong?